# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Class 'app\MyLib\MyClass' not found - Similar class working fine

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am creating a web application. I am relatively new to Laravel, and still learning. Anyway, here is my problem:

I am trying to include custom class into my project. I managed to include one class - Administrator, and tried to do the same with the other - Profesor, but despite the fact that first is working fine, the other does not.

1. I created files inside my app folder, subfolder Biblioteka, named Administrator and Profesor.
2. Inside each file I put:

   ```
   namespace app\Biblioteka;
   ```
3. Inside composer.json I made following alterations:

   ```
   "autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
       "App\\": "app/"
   },
   "classmap": [
       "database/seeds",
       "database/factories",
       "app/Biblioteka/Administrator",
       "app/Biblioteka/Profesor"
   ],
   "files": ["app/Biblioteka/Administrator.php",
             "app/Biblioteka/Profesor.php"]
   ```

   },
4. After that I run:

   ```
   php artisan route:clear
   php artisan cashe:clear
   composer dump-autoload
   ```

and got the following message:

```
    [RuntimeException]
    Could not scan for classes inside "app/Biblioteka/Administrator"
    which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
    dump-autoload [--no-scripts][-o|--optimize][-a|--classmap-
    authoritative][--apcu][--no-dev]
```

5. I included:

   ```
   use app\Biblioteka\Administrator;
   use app\Biblioteka\Profesor;
   ```

in files using mentioned classes.

Application is working for class Administrator, but not for class Profesor.

Class Administrator was created first. After everything started working properly I made class Profesor the same way as I did with Administrator. It reports the error at the line where constructor for the class is called. I cannot figure out why the second class is not working properly.

Thanks to anyone who can help me figure this one out :)

Comment: There's no need to add to the `classmap` and `files` blocks. Remove those lines, then just do `use App/Biblioteka/Administrator;` in your PHP files.

Comment: does app in the namespace with small letter is intended ? or is that the mistake?

Comment: because in your autoload it is written ``App\\`` so should your namespace be exactly, `namespace App\Biblioteka;`

Comment: @ceejayoz: Thank you, that did the trick. It is working fine now.

Comment: @Nina I'm glad that helped. Anything in the `app` directory can be referred in this manner without adding extra stuff to `composer.json`. You'd only need to add to that if you were putting your files outside of the `app` directory.

Comment: @ Eden Reich Thank you for trying to help. To answer, my app folder is named with small letter, so it is not a spelling error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to add to the `classmap` and `files` blocks if you're putting your custom classes in the `app` directory. Remove those lines, then just do use `App/Biblioteka/Administrator;` in your PHP files.

This bit:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
},
```

means that anything in the `app` directory can be referenced via the `App` namespace. Thus, for `app/Foo/Bar.php`, the class is referenced as `App\Foo\Bar`.

Comment: That is good to know. Most posts about class usage are over-complicating the issue, so it was quite a task to extrapolate from all the information. Thank you again for the help :)